# Search box, once focused, is extremely loud

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

To repro, click on the search box on the main site and type something.

A huge `#FFFF00` band of the loudest possible yellow appears.

[image: yellow]

It should be white.

Comment: If I make these edits the site will be black and white only. I'm trying to keep some color in the design.

Comment: @Sean There a huge variety of possibilities which you can choose from, and still loose that black and yellow. Just change the site palette to something easier on the eye? Some people do use the site for hours in a row, and do need something easy on the eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search input box has been changed to white.